# Send out thousands of individual emails without looping

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, loops

I have a site that people put stuff for sale on. 
Every month, every user who has something for sale will get sent an email by a windows service asking them if their item has been sold and giving them a custom link to click to confirm it hasn't (as it's against the user agreement for items to remain on the site that are sold).

First I must run a query to get all the unsold items and with the related users email. 
Currently I am looping all these and generate a custom email for each person and sending them out as individual emails.

```
   foreach (Item unsoldItem in unsoldItemsCollection)
        {
          //generate email

           string email = GenerateUnsoldEmail(itemName, itemPrice);
           Utils.Sendemail(unsoldItem .UserEmail, "no-reply@website.com", "Unsold Item", email);

        }
```

(this is kind of pseudo code, but this is pretty much what I'm doing)

My problem is there could possibly be thousands ( if it takes off, maybe millions :) ) of items in that loop all requiring emails, which I think is going to cause problems.

What other way could I do this?

Bex

Comment: What kind of problems do you expect?

It should be run as some kind of service so that if it takes a lot of time it doesn't harm the main site execution, of course.

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken, but I'm thinking if it's continuously looping millions of items and emailing each could that not take hours and use up server memory?
I was maybe thinking of some kind of mail merge.. I'm not sure?

Comment: Your loop is fine. In general it's good to ***get simple something working now***. Worry about "what might happen" situations when you come to them: if you have millions of users, you'll also be able to afford a good team to fix the problem!

Comment: Add email addresses in bcc and mail it to noreply@whatever.com

Comment: @Bex: if you write a mailmerge, you can't be calling one. [God Over Djin](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~mec/Summer2009/ABjorndahl/extension.html): it's turtles all the way down.

Comment: @sehe.. I don't really know what a mail merge is, but heard it emails lots of people so it sprung to mind as a possible solution

Comment: @Bex: mail merge is implemented as ... you guessed it - a loop; Each iteration sends a mail. I guess, mails to the same destination domain _might_ be combined into a single SMTP session. Then again, mail servers might refuse service for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do something for every item in a collection, you will have to use some kind of loop (or something equivalent, like recursion). There is no way around that.

You should stop worrying about potential problems. If you think this code will be a performance problem, measure it and find out how fast it actually is and how many emails it will handle.

You're worried it might take hours to send all the emails. Is that actually a problem? Why?

You're also worried it might take too much memory. If you can't fit all items into memory at once, you should process them in batches: get for example 1000 at a time, process them, and then get another 1000.

Comment: I can always rely on someone on stackoverflow to put my problem in perspective.. This is good advice and sounds like the best plan! 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would do this asynchronously so that the program is not halted until the current email is sent.

You can't mail merge since all emails are different; links inside it will be different... unless the body of the email has some sort of landing page that forces the user to log in and then redirects the user to a specific page where all the items for the user are listed and he is asked to remove the ones already sold. In that case, you could send an email instead of thousands.

[SmtpClient has an async version of the Send method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a windows service which will send all your emails once a day.

Or, even simpler, you can create a small console utility which does the same and run it as a scheduled task.